# print paragraphs that contain a line starting with some given string

Tags: text-processing, awk

My input file is as below, where records are separated by empty lines. I need to print the records (paragraphs) that have `xx` at the beginning of a line.

```
cat in.txt
```

```
a cfg
b hfh
c gfh
xx jhl
d kjl

a opi
b ghj
c tyu
yy xxx
d ghj

a xxx
b fgk
c ghf
z zxx
d ghj
```

My expected output is:

```
a cfg
b hfh
c gfh
xx jhl
d kjl
```

I tried the command below but it's not working:

```
awk -v RS='' -v ORS='\n\n' "/^XX/" in.txt
```

`^` is not working in this scenario

Comment: My records are split by  new line(single line).o/p will be like below                                                     
a cfg
b hfh
c gfh
xx jhl
d kjl

Comment: Renga, every line ends with a newline. The presence of the blank line means that records are separated by _two_ newlines

Comment: @Renga please [edit] your question and add your expected output there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's easier with `perl`:

```
perl -00 -ne 'print if /^xx/m' in.txt
```

There the `m` flag enables the multi-line mode where `^` and `$` not only match at the start and end of the record, but also at the start and end of each line within the record.

With `awk`, you could always do:

```
awk -v RS='' -v ORS='\n\n' '/(^|\n)xx/' in.txt
```

That is, match at the start of the record (`^`), or (`|`) following a newline character (`\n`).

Comment: Thx @Stéphane Chazelas its working, can you please explain (^|\n)

Comment: initially i tried ^ alone  and its not working,just got my desired out put by using the \n.just curious to know why ^ is not working here..

Comment: @Renga, `^` is the regexp operator that matches at the start of the subject. In `awk`'s `/.../` standalone operator, the *subject* is the full record, so `^` only matches at the start of the record, the start of the paragraph.

Comment: Thanks  @Stéphane Chazelas